# Cake PHP model for meta table relation

Tags: php, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I have a table called 'posts' having post details such as `id, title, owner, content.`
And i have another table to store the change history (`post_changes`) of the post table fields.

ie `post_id, created, field, old_value, new_value`;

I have model post.php

```
class Post extends AppModel {
   public $hasMany = array('PostChanges');
}

class PostChanges extends AppModel {
   public $belongsTo = array('Post');

  public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    /*
    foreach($this->data['PostChanges'] as $field => $value) {
        //if($field !== 'user_id') {
            $this->data['PostChanges']['field'] = $field;
            $this->data['PostChanges']['value'] = $value;
        //}
    }
    */

    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');          
    $this->data['PostChanges']['created'] = $db->expression('NOW()');
    var_dump($this->data['PostChanges']);
    return true;
}
}
```

// Var Dump from beforeSave

```
// Trace from Post beforeSave//
array(2) {
  ["PostChanges"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["comment"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PostChanges"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["this is a test comment from comment box 1"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["comment1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["PostChanges"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["this is a another test content from text area box 2"]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
  }
  ["Post"]=>
  array(8) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["priority"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["component"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["severity"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["milestone"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["version"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["modified"]=>
    object(stdClass)#49 (2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(10) "expression"
      ["value"]=>
      string(5) "NOW()"
    }
  }
}
// Trace from PostChanges beforeSave//
array(3) {
  ["this is a test comment from comment box 1"]=>
  NULL
  ["post_id"]=>
  string(2) "12"
  ["created"]=>
  object(stdClass)#50 (2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "expression"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "NOW()"
  }
}
// Trace from PostChanges beforeSave//
array(3) {
  ["this is a another test content from text area box 2"]=>
  NULL
  ["post_id"]=>
  string(2) "12"
  ["created"]=>
  object(stdClass)#47 (2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "expression"
    ["value"]=>
    string(5) "NOW()"
  }
}
```

In my controller am using

```
if ($this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data)) {

}
```

And My View

```
<div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('PostChanges.comment', array('rows' => '8', 'class' => 'form-control text_editor', 'placeholder' => '')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('PostChanges.comment1', array('rows' => '8', 'class' => 'form-control text_editor', 'placeholder' => '')); ?>
</div>
```

MY issue is am not getting `PostChanges.comment, PostChanges.comment1` in my beforeSave function. So I can't use my foreach loop there.

Am using cakephp 2.9

Comment: I want 2.9 too! Can you share it ;-) ? - Ontopic: I think it doesn't matter, but what is the result of the var_dump when you outcomment that "getDataSource" part? Maybe that is killing something? And why aren't you using the `$this->getDatasource()` method of the model itself? Because: what will be the value when you change the datasource your model has to use in the public variable? <-- disclaimer: I did not look it up, but I can imagine you want this to be dynamic too?

Comment: Another thing: why aren't you just making a copy of the entire row and store it in the same `posts` table? with some sort of `status` and `posts_group` key? I think that makes more sense, since then you keep ALL the properties of the `posts` table and model without having to create funky behaviours :) Then you could just say `$this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Post.post_group' => 2)));` and you have yourself the complete changelog. Also, you could create a `post_groups` table that contains some counter caches for a quick "how often did it change"-log. Just an idea ;-)

Comment: to make a copy of the post row will duplicate the all the field, if i just change only one field. that is why i make another table to hold only the changed fields.

Comment: My Question is that Why that Comment box values comes as Key of PostChanges class :(

Comment: You issue was "MY issue is am not getting PostChanges.comment, PostChanges.comment1 in my beforeSave function." so perhaps you can clarify your question a bit more? I thought you did NOT get the data at all, so that is why I was confussed :) And yes, you have a valid point there. But then I'm asking: how much duplicated data will you get? Because I think the posts table won't have that much "TEXT" or other char fields other than the `body` field? Which is the value that will be changed anyways, so .. My personal choice would be: offer some space for simplicity :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50945/discussion-between-coderex-and-jelmer)

Comment: will update the files soon, so you can easly figure out.

Comment: http://www.filesnack.com/files/cdzce95k 

my files are there with database